# Android SharedPrefs without Garbage

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, sharedpreferences

I am using Android shared prefs for saving user settings.  The problem is that it creates java objects every time you commit values.  A compromise is to only commit the changes every-so-often which works, but still generates garbage and may lose settings if the application ends soon after a change.

Is there a way to save prefs often and prevent garbage generation (or a usable alternative).  One could imagine allocating a fixed number of characters in shared-pref storage and updating it without creating strings but that would take a lot of effort to develop (ie converting floats, booleans and integers into characters without creating objects).  Besides, re-implementing framework code seems like a bad idea.

Comment: An alternative could be instantiatind an unique global SharepPreference editor and keep it alive till the app is finished? so you would always do your commits on the same object. Maybe it's not the most elegant or efficient solution.

Comment: Are you sure you are using right tool for the job? Have you considered using Binder or Broadcasts ?

Comment: @atok I need long-term persistence mechanism that does not create objects like strings.  Binder and Broadcasts are communication mechanisms.